# one-to-one relationships

Tags: model, core

I have a module where we are allowing partners to signup. there's a table called partner, and another table called partner_template, where I'm storing email templates for each partner.

the business logic requires that there only be one template per partner. how would I specify that in the model? or is it a matter of just ensuring that I do a limit=1 on all my queries?

also, what is the best way to get the related template? in other ORMs I've worked with, you get a handy 'getPartnerTemplate()' method on the partner object if there's a foreign key. from what I can see, my only option is to get the collection and limit it to one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a one-to-one relationship, have you consider moving `partner_template` column to your `partner` table?

If that solution doesn't work  for you, then you could make the PK in `partner_template` the `partner_id` (quick way to prevent duplicate in partner_template)

```
class Company_ModuleName_Model_Mysql4_Module extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {   
        ....
        $this->_isPkAutoIncrement = false;
    }
```

When saving your data

```
Mage::getModel('module/partner_template')->setId([partner_id])
    .....
    ->save();
```

When loading data

```
Mage::getModel('module/partner_template')->load([partner_id])
```

If you want to keep your `FK` relationship you could try

When saving your data

```
Mage::getModel('module/partner_template')->load([partner_id], 'partner_id')
    .....
    ->save();
```

When loading data

```
Mage::getModel('module/partner_template')->load([partner_id], 'partner_id')
```